# Getting music file from IOS without computer

Tags: ios, itunes, mail.app

My laptop is dead, thanks to an unplanned swim.  I have a song that that I transferred from the laptop to the iPad with iTunes.  I no longer have the vinyl LP that I ripped it from and can not obtain it.  Is there a way to get  the file into Mail as an attachment?  Or to pull it into a Windows computer that does not have iTunes and does not allow installing software?

Update: found a Windows XP that already has iTunes, but it has no internet, and I don’t see a way to access the Music on the iPad.  It can play the song but won’t let me put it in a file on the PC.

Comment: tbh, I think it would be simpler to put out feelers for the track & see if anyone has it - social media etc... or even mention it here, surreptitiously ;)

Comment: I have hunted for it.  The LP was privately produced at the college I and the author went to in 1972.  But, is it surreptitious enough :-) to mention her name at the time was Evie Johnson, the album title was “Life of a New Creation,” and the song title and last line were both “with love from God”?

Comment: Ah, OK - not so simple ;) I did find one reference to it online, but no sign of a copy of it in any physical/downloadable form. You *can* get tracks back from an iDevice, but you need to be able to install software. I know Windows can mount one as though it were an external drive, but I'm not sure how much of it you can directly access. I know people do it for photos, but idk about music.

Comment: I guess if I want it badly enough, I could buy a super cheap used computer and install iTunes.  Or hurry up and fix or replace my MacBook.  Or I could play it and sing it myself (extremely poorly!) and record that.  :-)

Comment: You should be able to back up the iPad to an iTunes computer.  From there you should be able to use a "pick files out of iTunes backup files" tool.

Comment: It is set for encrypted backup, unfortunately.  I deliberately set it up as a new iPad to avoid inheriting that UNWANTED setting from the old one.  But apparently something in iCloud vetoed my decision.